# Subquery returned more than 1 value in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In MS Sql.

```
SELECT a.SellerID, 
       SUM(TransactionFee) as TransactionFees,
SUM(Quantity*a.PriceItem) as TransactionValue,
COUNT(*) as OrdersWithTransactionFees, 
            SUM(Quantity) as Qty,
            (SELECT SUM(a.Quantity*a.PriceItem) as WholeMonthTransactionValue 
            from BuyProductDetails where SellerID = a.SellerID) as aa
FROM BuyProductDetails as a
WHERE MONTH(a.OrderDate)=3
AND YEAR(a.OrderDate)=2013
AND TransactionFee IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.SellerID
```

I have the above query... it can't seems to be able to run.

Basically, I have this table **BuyProductDetails** which stores all the orders from different Sellers.

Some orders will have TransactionFee.

Now, what I need is to calculate the total sales of these orders with TransactionFee, and the total sales for these sellers including those orders without TransactionFee.

The result set should have the following fields:

1. SellerID
2. Sum of Transaction fee
3. Sum of total sales
4. Number of Orders with Transaction fee
5. Qty ordered
6. Total sales for that seller

But when I run this sql, it returns the following error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I got the solution. It was from an answer by someone but I can't see his answer now on this page. Wonder why? Basically, just amend the subquery to the following: SELECT SUM(b.Quantity*b.PriceItem) as WholeMonthTransactionValue from BuyProductDetails b where b.SellerID = a.SellerID

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this ?

```
 SELECT a.SellerID, 
    SUM(TransactionFee) as TransactionFees,
    SUM(Quantity*a.PriceItem) as TransactionValue,
    COUNT(*) as OrdersWithTransactionFees, 
    SUM(Quantity) as Qty,
    MIN(a.WholeMonthTransactionValue) as WholeMonthTransactionValue
  FROM BuyProductDetails as a,
(SELECT b.SellerID, 
        SUM(b.Quantity*b.PriceItem) as WholeMonthTransactionValue,
        MONTH(b.OrderDate),
        YEAR(b.OrderDate)
 FROM BuyProductDetails b 
 GROUP BY b.SellerID,
    MONTH(b.OrderDate) as MonthID,
    YEAR(b.OrderDate) as YearID) as aa
    WHERE MONTH(a.OrderDate)=3
      AND YEAR(a.OrderDate)=2013
      AND TransactionFee IS NOT NULL
      AND a.SellerID = aa.SellerID
      AND MONTH(a.OrderDate)=aa.MonthID
      AND YEAR(a.OrderDate) = aa.YearID
    GROUP BY a.SellerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more effective option with [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression

```
SELECT a.SellerID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionFee IS NOT NULL THEN TransactionFee END) AS TransactionFees,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionFee IS NOT NULL THEN Quantity * PriceItem END) AS TransactionValue,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionFee IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as OrdersWithTransactionFees, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionFee IS NOT NULL THEN Quantity END) as Qty,
       SUM(Quantity * PriceItem) AS WholeMonthTransactionValue         
FROM BuyProductDetails AS a
WHERE MONTH(a.OrderDate) = 3 AND YEAR(a.OrderDate) = 2013
GROUP BY a.SellerID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bdb9/1)

**Or merely add correct alias in the subquery**

```
SELECT a.SellerID, 
       SUM(TransactionFee) as TransactionFees,
       SUM(Quantity*a.PriceItem) as TransactionValue,
       COUNT(*) as OrdersWithTransactionFees, 
       SUM(Quantity) as Qty,
       (SELECT SUM(d.Quantity * d.PriceItem)
        FROM BuyProductDetails d
        WHERE d.SellerID = a.SellerID) as WholeMonthTransactionValue 
FROM BuyProductDetails as a
WHERE MONTH(a.OrderDate)=3
AND YEAR(a.OrderDate)=2013
AND TransactionFee IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.SellerID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bdb9/3)